# Facebook application only accessible by admin user account

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I created a facebook app to share articles from a website. When I'm connected from the app's admin account, I can share articles, but when I try to share articles from another account, this error is displayed: An error has occurred, please try again later
This is the used script:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: '1488318304714792', status: true, cookie: true,
xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root_single_post').appendChild(e);
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.share_button_single_post').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: '<?php echo utf8_encode(strtoupper($chaine2)); ?>',
link: $("input[type='hidden'][name='"+this.id+"1']").val(),
picture: 'http://www.bdo.com.tn/BDO-facebook-logo.png',
caption: 'www.bdo.com.tn',
description: $("input[type='hidden'][name='"+this.id+"2']").val()+'...',
message: ''
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: is the app enabled as the other user?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "enabled as the other user?"

Comment: Did you make the app accessible to the public on the 'Status & Review' tab of the app settings?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check you're not in sandbox mode first.

Have you gone to "Status and Review" in the option panel on the left, and then clicked "yes" for the question "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

This should make the app accessible to all FB users.

Comment: Yes, sandbox checkbox are replaced by "Do you want to make..." but the "yes no button" id disabled!!! I can't chek it! to make the app accessible

Comment: @Aminesrine This means your App needs to be reviewed before you can set it to live. Are you intending for the app to be listed as an app in the FB App Center? If not you should change the **App Center Listed Platforms** settings in **App Details** to reflect that. Sometimes this can avoid the review process.

Comment: I added "Website" plateforme, then I should fill all App details? or should I send "Review Submission Form"

Comment: Yes. I would send the review submission form and follow the procedures that Facebook outline from there. It's likely necessary due to some of the permissions and features you're requesting in the app. Without more information on this I can't help.